# Join multiple Table Values Into a String

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a query built into a c# program to produce a csv  (a pick list for a warehouse), i need to extend this files functionality and add another column in which lists all the items bundled with the main product. The bundled items information is across 2 tables.

Here is the main query i currently have:

```
SELECT  si.ItemNumber,
        si.ItemTitle,
        ooi.nQty


FROM    Open_OrderItem ooi
        INNER JOIN StockItem si on si.pkstockItemID=ooi.fkStockItemId
```

I need to add another column to list the ItemNumbers Of LinkStockItemId each one ideally would be listed with a comma separating them and the Quantity

The table links to the main current query on pkStockitemId but the result will be all pkLinkStockItemId listed with a comma seperated

Image of the tables below they are simple but i cant seem to get my head around any of the information i have found on the web as i only know basic sql and help would be awesome thank you in advance!

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5hVa.png)

Comment: sorry i have edited the post, its mysql

Comment: Look up `GROUP_CONCAT() ... GROUP BY`. You haven't given us enough information to allow us to offer actual answers to your question.

Comment: Sorry Ollie this is my first question on this board so i apolagise if it wanst very clear, ill take a look at this GROUP_CONCAT. Out of interest and hopefully to improve the question i ask next time can you tell me what more information you would need in order to help with this particular question

Comment: it'll be helpful if you will add your desired output.